# gitlab CI YAML: combination of variables

Tags: gitlab, yaml, cicd

I manually run my pytest as following:

> $ pytest test_a.py --opt0="123 456" --opt1="789 abc"

In YAML file .gitlab-ci, I woud like to define something similar:

```
test_a:
  scripts:
    - pytest test_a.py ${OPTIONS}
  variables:
    OPTIONS: --opt0="123 456" --opt1="789 abc"
```

It turns out that the value of `opt0` is `123 456 --opt1="789 abc"`

Do you have any idea of what happens and how to pass the arguments correctly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very minor issue, all you need to do is surround your `OPTIONS` value with single quote.

Also maybe it is a typo, but it should be just `script` whereas in your snippet it is `scripts`. :)

```
test_a:
  script:
    - pytest test_a.py ${OPTIONS}
  variables:
    OPTIONS: '--opt0="123 456" --opt1="789 abc"'
```

I tried it with echoing the script command.

[image]